# Pagespeed insights - request working locally, but not from AWS server

Tags: rest, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to test a website using google pagespeed insights. There is this simple GET method for testing using google pagespeed insights API. I am trying to automate the process and I am using simple rest template. When I run my app locally it works perfectly fine, also when using Postman, or simply requesting from Chrome browser. The problem is when I try to request data from my AWS server. Then it returns an error. This is an example request.

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.infojobs.net

I tried adding different headers etc. but the problem is very peculiar since when I try to request from postman there are no additional headers.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "lighthouse",
    "reason": "lighthouseError",
    "message": "Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST.             
        Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. 
        Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is 
        properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 405)"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. 
Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure 
you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding 
to all requests. (Status code: 405)"
 }
}
```

I know this is not a strictly code problem, but I have ran out of ideas how to tackle the problem and what could be the issue. Since the site actually gets tested it is not the problem of the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with following code via curl and all seems working:

```
$pageURL = 'https://www.infojobs.net';
$APIkey = "YOUR API KEY";

$baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed";
$url = $baseURL.'?url='.urlencode($url).'&key='.$APIkey;

$curl = curl_init();

$curl_options = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_options);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($response, true));
echo "<pre>";
```

Check it please and let me know if it works for you.
I have similar problem but I think it will be something in server config. Or have you fixed it already?